# When we click outside the Div of Bootstrap Popup , the popup closes . How to track the close-event of Bootstrap Popup?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popup

When we click outside the Div of Bootstrap Popup , the popup closes . How to track the close-event of Bootstrap Popup ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle the modal closing event in Twitter Bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319171/how-to-handle-the-modal-closing-event-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201843/2332336

### Bootstrap 3

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals -> Events

### Bootstrap 2.3.2

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals -> Events