# multiple modals and data-dismiss="modal"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My web application uses multiple custom modals. The first modal always loads correctly, but further on modals don't load (the screen just greys out). I think the issue comes along with the attribute in the close button:

```
data-dismiss="modal"
```

Apparently, a solution is to attach an event listener to the button calling `.modal('hide')`. Is this the proper way of representing multiple modals? I am worried about simply removing `data-dismiss="modal"` as I don't understand its functionality well enough.

Comment: Do you have `class="close"` on the buttons as well? You really shouldn't have to manually close these.

Comment: If you really need to add an event listener, here is a question + answer that shows how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319171/how-to-handle-the-modal-closing-event-in-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "proper way" to doing things. Depending on your need there is a more effective way to do things. I think in this case you are better off using the event attached to the button and hiding the modals using their ids.

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

### [This is a good jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/MGbXk/)