# Bootstrap - Open modal while another modal is open and keep 'modal-open' class in body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a new Bootstrap modal when I click a button inside another open modal. It works fine, but the problem is that the 'modal-open' class of the *body* tag just disappears, and so an scroll for the entire page appears.

When I click the button in the modal, in code-behind I do this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upMain, typeof(UpdatePanel), "Tipo descuento seleccionado", "$('#DtosModal').modal('show'); $('#tipoDtoModal').modal('hide');", true);
```

What can I do to keep that class in the *body* tag?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: If I change

```
$(document)
   .on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(document.body).addClass('modal-open') }) 
   .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open') })
```

in bootstrap.js for

```
$(document) 
   .on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { document.body.className += ' modal-open'; }) 
   .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(" modal-open", ""); })
```

I solve the problem. Any other more 'orthodox' ideas?

Answer (score 6):

> Any other more 'orthodox' ideas?

Yes i have, but a very 'orthodox' one : )

```
// close the modal anyway
$('#' + modalName).modal('hide');
setTimeout(function() {
    // needs to be in a timeout because we wait for BG to leave
    // keep class modal-open to body so users can scroll
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
}, 400);
```

I'm working with http://bootboxjs.com/
there the callback only fires just after i pressed the action button. so it does not wait until the background disappeared.

For the Twitter Bootstrap modal seem to be a proper solution for the callback. See here:
[How to handle the modal closing event in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319171/how-to-handle-the-modal-closing-event-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

The solution for bootstrap it would be:
(La solución para bootstrap sería:)

```
$('#nameOfModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

Comment: That is a perfect answer. Simple and accurate thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Use the event [shown.bs.modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

```
$('#DtosModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  $('body').addClass('modal-open');
})
```

Be careful to use **shown.bs.modal** and not **show.bs.modal**.