# Open Modal in front of Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

quick question (hopefully?). I have a modal (click the button and the thing/content pops up) - inside the modal I have text that I wanted to have someone click and it opens another modal in front.

The intial modal is:

```
<button class="btn btn-two shortcode-popup-trigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-group-5">MORE INFO</button>
```

Then inside I used the exact same line but changed the modal ID to the other modal I wanted to open. This works, except the new modal opens BEHIND the current one. Is anyone able to help me with this? I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It's the same Modal module so guessing `.modal`'s z-index is same for both modals. Why don't you try different `z-index`es for each modal?

```
#modal-group-4 {
    z-index: 400;
}

#modal-group-5 {
    z-index: 500;
}
```

If this doesn't work. Then you can try closing the first modal and then showing it back when the second modal is closed. Something like this,

To close the first modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-two shortcode-popup-trigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-group-5" onclick="jQuery('#modal-group-4').modal('toggle');">MORE INFO</button>
```

To reopen the first modal, we need to listen for closing event of the second one,

```
$('#modal-group-5').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    jQuery('#modal-group-4').modal('toggle');
})
```

Note: The above method is supported in Bootstrap 3 only. For lower versions, use this

```
$('#modal-group-5').on('hidden', function () {
    jQuery('#modal-group-4').modal('toggle');
})
```

[Method # 2 Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319171/how-to-handle-the-modal-closing-event-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

In your "Html" page, make sure your "modal-group-4" modal is above the "modal-group-5".  If your modal-group-5 is above modal-4 then modal-group-5 will come out behind modal-group-4.

Try that.