# How to reset scroll postition when modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

i'm trying to reset the scroll postion after close modal.
I did this but it not working

```
$("#modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  $("#content").scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319171/how-to-handle-the-modal-closing-event-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: i use bootstrap 4.3.1

Comment: thanks for the link, i use hide.bs.modal instead of hiden.bs.modal