# In Twitter Bootstrap, how do I unbind an event from the closing of a modal dialog?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a function that is bound to the action of hiding a modal dialog.

I'm using code similar to the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close?rq=1) question.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

However, this dialog may get reopened for editing, and, when that happens, I don't necessarily want to run this code. Is there a way to "unbind" the function so that it is no longer run when the dialog closes? I haven't found anything in [the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Comment: Unbind the modal events or the events contained within the modal itself?

Comment: Unbind the modal events, if I'm understanding your question correctly. I want to unbind whatever is supposed to happen on 'hidden'.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do something like to unbind all events tied to the modal element:

**Unbind all events in the modal:**

```
/* First option */
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).unbind(); // or $(this)        
});

/* Second option is to call it directly when needed */
$('#myModal').unbind();
```

**The Bootrap modal also have specific events tied to it**, so you can also specify which event(s) you want to unbind.

```
/* Events are 'hidden', 'hide', 'show', 'shown' */
$('#myModal').unbind(/* specific event here */);
```

If you wish to remove events tied to the content of the modal, you can simply just empty the elements within `$('#myModal').empty()` and unbind those elements appropriately.

Comment: $('#myModal').unbind(); works, but its a bit too promiscuous... it also unbinds the ability to close the window using the "X" in the corner.

Comment: When you mentioned, you want to unbind the modal events, I figured the entire modal include its children needs unbinding too. Or do you just need to unbind the 'hidden' event? Something like $('#myModal').unbind('hidden').

Answer (score 21):

Use:

```
$('#myModal').off('hidden');
```

Why not unbind?

> As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Source: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).