# How to use jquery to show an element after JSON data is sent back to page

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, hide, show

On page 1, user clicks an image and a pop-up window allows an image file upload. The PHP page running this echo's back a json_encoded string that will include a variable called 'id'.

Here is an example of the response string:

```
"{"state":200,"message":null,"result":"..\/0images\/listimg\/mod\/20141215064959.jpeg","id":"570"}"
```

When the pop-up modal closes, I would like an element (that was previously hidden on page 1) to now be displayed. The element is:

```
<div class="edit_right">
```

My logic is to show the element if an 'id' is sent as JSON data, thus if ID is not null, element will show.
The JS I am troubleshooting is

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".edit_right").hide();
        });
    $('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        function handleResponse(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
        $.getJSON(crop-avatar.php)
            .done(function(data) {
             if (data.id !== null){
              $(".edit_right").show();
             } else {
            $(".edit_right").hide();
            }
         });
       })
    </script>
```

and is located right before the end body tag. This script doesn't work, the element is always hidden. How can I correct this?

Comment: don't forget to run your function .. handleResponse();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the URL into `$.getJSON()` so it knows what page to retrieve the data from, and I don't know why you're passing `data` to `handleResponse()`, it has no effect in that function.

Comment: i changed to this      $.getJSON(crop-avatar.php)
        .done(function(data) {   but didn't show element

Comment: When you go to `crop-avatar.php` directly does it return the JSON array you are expecting?  Are you sure the function is even being triggered?  If you put `alert('here');` in the first line of `handleResponse()`, is it even being called?

Comment: i have to run the function

Comment: Right, you want to call the function when your modal closes.

Comment: Is 'hidden.bs.modal' an event on your modal that you can hook into?  Also put surround `crop-avatar.php` with `""`.

Comment: i just caught that. And yes I believe so:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close

Answer (score 1):

I think the data that returns in handleResponse is a json string so you don't have to do additional getJSON on that.
Do

```
function handleResponse(data){
console.log(data);
}
```

If it shows a json string then you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

you are not calling $.getJson with a parameter

Answer (score 1):

from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    // Do something
});
```

so what you need to do is:

```
function handleResponse(data){
   $.getJSON('path/to/your/php-file.php').done(function(data){
        // Do something
    })
}
```

Also don't forget to call handleResponse()!