# Callback on close dialog or dismiss

Tags: bootbox

Is there an option with `bootbox` that calls a function when the user closes the dialog via the 'x' button? I did not find a documentation about this when using `bootbox.dialog()`.

Are there something like this:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message : 'My message',
    callback : function() {
        // User is closin' the dialog. Come on do somethin'
    }
});
```

I even tried `close`, `closing` and `closeCallback` instead of `callback`, but non of them worked.

Answer (score 5):

I figured that it's possible to achieve that by the `onEscape` option (`callback`), by looking into the source code of `bootbox repository`.

```
bootbox.dialog(function(){
    message: 'My message',
    onEscape: function() {
        // User is closin' the dialog. Come on do somethin'
    }
});
```

Although, this does not provide the ability of preventing the closing action. Even returning false does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(#yourModal).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () 
     {
        alert("closed");

     });
```

Got the answer from here:
[Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Then you could return false to prevent closing