# Video keeps playing after modal is closed Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an object that loads videos into the DOM via twitter bootstrap's modal when you click on an image, [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/go5q9zoe/2/). The video works fine in all browsers except in Firefox. So after some research, I was able to get the video to play in Firefox, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1edf7skt/55/). The only thing now is that the `for` loop stops after the first iteration and I can't get the video to stop playing after you close the modal. I've searched everywhere for a solution to the stop the video from playing and can't figure out why the `for` loop stops after the first iteration. I'm learning so any help/insight would be highly appreciated!

**JavaScript**

```
var dataCollection = {
  'videoData': [
    {
      'id'      : 0,
      'title'   : 'Badminton',
      'company' : 'Pepto Bismol',
      'gifLink' : '...',
      'srcMp4'  : '...',
      'srcWebm' : '...',
      'srcOgv'  : '...',
      'poster'  : '...'
      },
      { ...
     ]
    };

var videos = $('#video');
var modalContent = $('#video-modal');

var appendVideo = function(videoObj) {
  var poster = videoObj.poster;
  var srcMp4 = videoObj.srcMp4;
  var srcWebm = videoObj.srcWebm;
  var srcOgv = videoObj.srcOgv;
  var playpause = document.querySelector('video');
  var stop = document.querySelector('#myModal,.close');
  var video = $('<div class="video col-sm-12 col-md-3"><img src="' + poster + '" data-title="' + videoObj.title + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></div>');

  var videoPlayer = $('<video preload="auto" controls><source src="' + srcMp4 + '" type="video/mp4;"><source src="' + srcWebm + '" type="video/webm;"><source src="' + srcOgv + '" type="video/ogv;"></video>');
  videos.append(video);

video.find('img').click(function(e) {
  modalContent.append(videoPlayer);
  // debug
  // alert(videoObj.srcMp4);
  // console.log(videoObj.srcMp4);
});

 playpause.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (video.paused || video.ended) video.play();
    else video.pause();
 });

$('#myModal, .close').on('click', function(){
  video.pause();
  video.currentTime = 0;
  progress.value = 0;
  modalContent.find('video').remove();
});

for (var i = 0; i < dataCollection.videoData.length; i++) {
  var obj = dataCollection.videoData[i];
    appendVideo(obj);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container row">
  <div id="video"></div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <div class="modal-body" id="video-modal"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***EDIT***
Updated working code, works on Firefox, Chrome and Safari:

```
var videos = $('#video');
var modalContent = $('#video-modal');
var bye = $('#myModal, .close');

var appendVideo = function(videoObj) {
  var poster = videoObj.poster;
  var srcMp4 = videoObj.srcMp4;
  var srcWebm = videoObj.srcWebm;
  var srcOgv = videoObj.srcOgv;
  var video = $('<div class="video col-sm-12 col-md-3"><img src="' + poster + '" data-title="' + videoObj.title + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></div>');

  var videoPlayer = $('<video preload="none" controls poster="' + poster + '"><source src="' + srcMp4 + '" type="video/mp4;"><source src="' + srcWebm + '" type="video/webm;"><source src="' + srcOgv + '" type="video/ogg;"></video>');

videos.append(video);
  video.find('img').click(function(e) {
  modalContent.append(videoPlayer);
  // debug
  // alert(videoObj.srcMp4);
  // console.log(videoObj.srcMp4);
});

bye.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  var currentVideo = $('video');
  currentVideo.remove();
});

};

for (var i = 0; i < dataCollection.videoData.length; i++) {
  var obj = dataCollection.videoData[i];
  appendVideo(obj);
}
```

Comment: you need to attach to the close modal event, and stop your video that way, this is a fairly common problem tbh (and a pain)! Some suggestions in the accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems to be working.

Add this JS after you have loaded the above script (just before the closing body tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        var videos = $('#video');
        video.pause()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OP is not using youtube... nor iframes

Answer (score 0):

You can stop video using javascript:

```
 var video = document.getElementById("video");
 function stopVideo() {
     video.pause();
     video.currentTime = 0;
 }
```

and call **stopVideo** function on modal close event

Comment: i tried it updating the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1edf7skt/73/) but cant get it to work...

Comment: i checked video is getting paused so do u want to reset that video after close

Comment: I'd like the video to stop playing...but on my fiddle, it keeps playing(in firefox)