# Bootstrap 3.x: how to have url change upon clicking modal trigger?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Using **Bootstrap v3.3.5**

I have a webpage that is using the url `domain.com/companies`

This is my trigger for the modal in that webpage.

```
<a href="#modal-add-company" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-effect-ripple btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Company</a>
```

This will successfully trigger this modal

```
<div id="modal-add-company" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```

However, the url does not change to `domain.com/companies#modal-add-company`

Nor does the url `domain.com/companies#modal-add-company` actually trigger the modal on reload.

What do I need to do to have the following:

1. change the url to `domain.com/companies#modal-add-company` whenever I trigger the modal and the modal is shown, and
2. if i directly type the url `domain.com/companies#modal-add-company`, the modal is shown

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using jQuery this could be a viable solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window.location.hash).modal('show');
   $('a[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
   });
});
```

Assuming you have a trigger to close the modal like this:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

You can add this below the code block above:

```
$('button[data-dismiss="modal"]').click(function(){
     var original = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
     history.replaceState({}, document.title, original);
 });
```

And assuming you want escape button to still be able to close the modal, and also change the url the whole code block would look like this:

```
    $(window.location.hash).modal('show');
    $('a[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    });

    function revertToOriginalURL() {
        var original = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
        history.replaceState({}, document.title, original);
    }

    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        revertToOriginalURL();
    });
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201843/80353 about how to use modal close event.

Comment: Awesome ! Keep it up .

Comment: Neat solution, I like it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this on **onclick event** of the button that triggers the modal

```
onclick="window.location.hash = 'modal-add-company';"
```

And write following script code after bootstrap.js

```
<script>
if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == 'modal-add-company'){
    $('#modal-add-company').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

It should work.