# Add URL hash when on click bootstrap modal anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an anchor to open a modal:

```
<a href="#delete-{{ $id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete btn-fla details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remove_property_modal">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

The problem is that the url is not changing from `http://example.com` into `http://example.com/#delete-4` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34154370/4314952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change url hash on show.bs.modal event of bootstrap modal ([docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
         if (typeof (e.relatedTarget) != "undefined") {
             window.location.hash = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');
         } 
     });
});
```