# Jquery open a custom modal link instead of hashtag for popup maker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal when a user is clicking it. I'm currently using a popup maker.

ex. www.hello.com/test

the /test would be the # variable of the modal link.

```
<a href="#test" class="hello"> Im a hidden modal in a link menu</a>
```

I tried reading the popup maker documentation and i need to do this instead.

```
<a href="#popmake-123" class="hello"> Im a hidden modal in a link menu</a>
```

But when i tried entering the link like this "www.hello.com/#popmake-123" there's no auto modal showing.

I tried with these codes so far.

```
$(window.location.hash).modal('show');
$('a.popmake-user-login').click(function(){
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

but nothing's happening. Thank you in advance guys.

(link source)
[Bootstrap 3.x: how to have url change upon clicking modal trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154370/bootstrap-3-x-how-to-have-url-change-upon-clicking-modal-trigger)

Comment: Just a quick thing you can test: full URLs need to include `http(s)://`

Comment: Hello @ChrisG I just tried it and that didn't worked out. thanks

Comment: where you added this code? header or footer?

Comment: @vel i added the code on footer.

Comment: try with `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @Vel thank you for helping me but it currently stating 

"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function". im currently figuring out a solution

Comment: answer updated. please check

Comment: did you include the boostrap.js?

Comment: Thanks @vel. forgot to add the js for bootstrap :)

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(window.location.hash).modal('show');
   jQuery('a.popmake-user-login').click(function(){
      window.location.hash = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```