# jQuery/Bootstrap 4 : using window.location.hash for getting modal hash in URL gives "#undefined"

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to work with WordPress and a custom loop to display images in a Flickity carousel. Each image displays different articles in a Bootstrap Modal on click. Everything is working correctly.
Thanks to Jonathan Ortega on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34242955/8137129) I nearly succeed to add the modal hash in the URL depending of the user click. The problem is that I'm getting ".../#undefined" in the URL instead of the exact modal name. The weird thing is that if I'm loading the page with "www.MYWEBSITE.com/#MYMODAL" this is working really great, the page successfully opens on the desired modal. But that's not working on click.

Here is the jQuery script, on the header :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// some other script....

$(window.location.hash).modal('show');
    $('li[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){
       window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});

});
```

And my custom WordPress loop involving the modal event :

```
<div class="slider slider--columns" data-arrows="true" data-paging="true">
<ul class="slides">

<?php 

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'MY_POST_TYPE',
'posts_per_page' => -1 
);

$MYPOSTTYPE = new WP_Query ($args);
if ($MYPOSTTYPE->have_posts() ):
    while ($MYPOSTTYPE->have_posts() ): $MYPOSTTYPE->the_post();

?>

<li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php the_field('MODAL_ID_THING') ?>">
<div id="MY_ID" style="background-image: url(BGIMAGE.png) !important;"><img style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Image" src="dummyimage.png"></div>
</li>

<?php

endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
</div>
</ul>
```

As you can see the modal is called through `<?php the_field('MODAL_ID_THING') ?>`. At first I was thinking the jQuery script didn't like the PHP loop, so instead I entered a simple value referring to one of my modals like "#modalnumber1" just for testing, but the same thing happened.
I also tried to change `$(window.location.hash).modal('show')` in the script with `$(window.location.hash).modal('toggle')`, same problem.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `$('li[data-toggle="modal"]')` **does not** have `href` attribute, I suppose you want to use `data-target`:

```
$('li[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){
    window.location.hash = $(this).data('target');
});
```

Comment: Damn of course, sorry I'm not really reactive when the subject is about jQuery, I now understand way more the meaning of the " window.location.hash = $(this)... " line. Thank you very much for your fast answer !!