# change a input field value on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a modal, the thing is that I want to change the value of an input field based on it. If modal is open value is "Update" when the modal is not displayed, the value is "create".

I tried like this but since it is executed only one time on page load it's not what I want.

```
if (($("element").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown) {
     $('#action-description').val('Update');
} else {
     $('#action-description').val('Create');         
}
```

And the input field:

```
<input type="text" id="action-description"  name="action-description" value="">
```

I need to make something on change so I also tried like this:

```
$('#modalElement').on('hidden', function(){
    $('#action-description').val('Create');
});
```

But I can't make it work!

Comment: What is the difference between **modal is open** and **modal is not hidden** in the above description?

Comment: What library are you using to show the modal? Most of the modal libraries provide callbacks for open/close event, you can use that.

Comment: Your code should be binded to an event so that it is fired each time. For example to the event that display or hide the modal.

Comment: I am afraid `$("element").data('bs.modal') || {}` will return a truthy value every time.

Comment: @hamism sorry I edited my question.

Comment: @TrungDQ I'm using bootstrap modals

Comment: So then you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close.

Comment: @Egjupss Not sure how you put your code to open the modal, it could be easier if you could provide a JSFiddle to reproduce your problem. It's very helpful for people who trying to help you and sometimes you may resolve the problem by yourself while doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. You can just convert it to a function and open the modal using jquery only.

So, write a function as:

```
function openModal(){

    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    if (($("element").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown) {
        $('#action-description').val('Update');
    } 

}
```

Also you can write a similar function to close the modal on clicking cross or cancel button(if you have any)

```
function closeModal(){

    $('#myModal').modal('hide');  
    $('#action-description').val('Create'); 
}
```