# change css style after modal is hide

Tags: jquery, css, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

when I click on my table row there appear modal window and change "tr" background-color indicates for each row was modal opened. However, when I close my modal background color of tr remains the same. How to change it to default?

```
<tr class='revisions'>
      <td>{{ $revision->date_of_revision->format('d.m.Y') }}
      </td>

<td class="text-right">
                    <a  
                       data-toggle="modal" 
                       data-target="#revisionEdit" 
                       class='btn btn-warning revisionEdit'>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </a>

</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're changing the color with JavaScript then you can use the Bootstrap modal events to change it back when hidden.

```
    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("selector").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
    });
```

According to [w3fools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp):

> **show.bs.modal** Occurs when the modal is about to be shown.
>   **shown.bs.modal**    Occurs when the modal is fully shown (after CSS
>   transitions have completed)
>     **hide.bs.modal**  Occurs when the modal
>   is about to be hidden 
>  **hidden.bs.modal**    Occurs when the modal is
>   fully hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event on closing of the modal popup. Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close#answer-13201843)

> $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
>       // do something… })

See [getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)