# How to set focus on input text field after bootstrap model is closed?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I did used `$('#advocate').focus();` after model is about to close but is does not worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. `$('#inputId').focus();` works fine when modal is hidden or when input is part of open modal. Focus after modal closing should work(other functions like `$('#inputId').val()` works fine), but it doesn't:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#inputId').focus();
});
```