# Using Keyboard to Navigate Bootstrap Modal Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, lightbox, bootstrap-lightbox

I'm building a portfolio webpage and have incorporated [W3School's Bootstrap Lightbox.](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox)

What I am trying to do now is make when you click outside the image, the modal closes; similar to other lightboxes. I also want to add in navigation by using the arrow keys and escape key.

I have searched Stack Overflow and have found questions similar to what I am asking but I do not understand how to add jquery to do what I want. Other lightbox modals work fine when you click outside the box to close it, but why not here? Thank you in advance.

From Bootstrap's page:

`$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})`

What do I put in the // do something..?

Comment: Have you written any code where we can start from it ?

Comment: I have looked to this page. Let me know if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close?rq=1

Comment: Can you put code that you have done??? because the link that is given by you is not a bootstrap. It is a CSS and written script written by W3School it self.