# Reload page after a particular modal is closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have two modals on a page. I only want one to refresh the parent page once closed. However, even if I add the code to do so both modals refresh the page after closing. Any idea why?

```
<script>
    $(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal');
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal2').removeData('bs.modal');
    location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

Modal 1 call:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="modal_target.cfm?M=#MLink#" class="btn btn-#bg_color#">#CP#</a>
```

Modal 2 call:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" href="modal_AmendCP.cfm?M=#MLink#" title="view details" class="btn btn-primary">#Measure#</a>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your functions are being fired on the same event of modal closing on `$(document.body)`.

You should change it to the be triggered on modal objects only:

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal');
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#myModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal2').removeData('bs.modal');
    location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

[From the Bootstrap Documentation:](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/)

> **hidden.bs.modal**: This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Answer (score 0):

you should select exact modal to add Event Listener.
if selector is "document.body", event will fire for both.
in your code: function called for 'hidden.bs.modal' is only

```
function () {
$('#myModal2').removeData('bs.modal');
location.reload();
}
```

it replace

```
function () {
$('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal');
}
```

because it is declared later.