# Execute function on Bootstrap Modal hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to make a function call whenever my Bootstrap modal closes (hides). This means whenever someone clicks off the modal, if they press escape, or if they click the "x" close button.

Using  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {}); does not capture when someone presses escape or clicks off the modal, it only captures the clicking of the close button.

How can I execute a function WHENEVER my modal closes and not just on trigger of the close button?

Comment: The hidden event fires no matter how the modal is closed. http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/4859/

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 3 / 4**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

See [Events Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

**Bootstrap 2.3.2**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

See [Events bootstrap 2.3.2](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

You can try listening to these events.

---

Would it be possible to know the version of Bootstrap that you use?

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in the end it was because elements were being dynamically added and I had to re-structure my jquery to actually get those new elements.